# How to edit an email address on iOS

Tags: ios, mobile-mail

I mistyped someone's email, now I choose "Send again"

But i can't edit their email address: backspacing selects the entire email and deletes all of it, tapping in the middle of the email selects all of it, and I can't even drag the cursor (force touch or hold space) into the middle of it

How can I change an email address that is already entered in the "to" field

Answer (score 0):

The [code turns text into an un-editable address object](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/441400/5472) here.

I do not believe any shortcut or manipulation allows this. Instead, save the contact to your address book and edit it there if you may need this more than once. Or delete and dictate or type again the correct address.